# API для эмодзи статусов ВК

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, vk-mini-apps, emoji

Есть ли методы API ВКонтакте для установки эмодзи статуса?

Эмодзи статус могут ставить приложения "Covid-19" от ВКонтакте и "Школа дружбы" от My Little Pony, но можно ли добавить такой же функционал в свое приложение или скрипт?

Comment: Приложение вк с эмодзи статусами vk.com/emoji_app

Answer (score 1):

В документации VK API этот метод не описан, но при смене эмодзи-статуса отправляется запрос, типа такого:

```
POST /method/status.setImage HTTP/1.1
Host: api.vk.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 184
Origin: https://vk.com
Referer: https://vk.com/
Te: trailers
Connection: close

?api_id=7362610&method=status.setImage&format=json&v=5.103&status_id=35&access_token=secret&request_id=13
```

Где `status_id=xxx` - как раз то, что нужно. Осталось найти все возможные

Answer (score 0):

Для получения всех статусов приложения, воспользуйтесь запросом `status.getImageList`

```
api.vk.com/method/status.getImageList?
    api_id=**id**&method=status.getImageList&format=json&v=5.131&
    access_token=**token**
```

Для установки статуса `status.setImage`:

```
api.vk.com/method/status.setImage?
    api_id=**id**&method=status.setImage&format=json&v=5.131&
    access_token=**token**&status_id=**id**&request_id=**id**
```